# Masked Input plugin acts strange on mobile device?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I am using the masked input plugin from the following [website](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).  Frop a laptop, the mask works fine for a MAC Address, for example, as I enter e1, it skips over the colon and I continue entering, however, if I access the page from a mobile device, and my intention is to enter 11:22:33:44:55:66, the cursor always stays in the front and it gets entered as 66:55:44:33:22:11.

Comment: How many mobile devices have you tried and which ones?